# Image Recognition Riddle

Tags: computer-puzzle

Given this picture:

[image: Character Glyphs]

And this picture:

[image: Word Glyphs]

Could you solve the riddle?

Nota bene: The mysterious dot prints below the letters are the UTF-8-encoded solutions (doubly encoded in the case of the characters, you will see).

(Clarifying: We search an algorithm that receives 2 images like the above and prints out the recognized words. No cheating by checking the little dots! Behave yourselves! :-))

Any language goes.

If you want to see my attempt or use my language: check tinybrain.de/1004646 - it doesn't work yet though (score 4/9).

Good luck! Any questions?

:D

Comment: Riddles currently must be posted in the [sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox) before being posted on the main site. However as this isn't a normal riddle, (not entirely sure it *is* a riddle) I won't close

Comment: And welcome to puzzling! This is most definitely an interesting and unusual puzzle

Comment: This is asking for a computer program... perhaps it belongs on a different SE?

Comment: I don't understand this. Why do you have a character chart with the rightmost three columns displayed on the left? Why are there multiple `/` characters? Why do `"`, `'`, `/`, and a few other characters seem to have more bits than the others? Are these hints, or things that we need to figure out, or are you just trying to make it confusing? Are you challenging us to decode a hidden message, or are you asking us to help you write a computer program to do it? Are we *supposed* to use the dots, or aren't we? Please do not respond in comments; edit your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @IanMacDonald The OP asks for an *algorithm*. Very different thing. You could describe an algorithm in words without knowing the syntax of any computer language in which a program might be written for running that algorithm. Algorithm-puzzles *are* on topic here. E.g. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/183/twelve-balls-and-a-scale http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/horses-and-tracks